# SAPUI5 fixed height for scroll container rendered dynamically

Tags: scrollview, sapui5

I am trying to set a fixed height for a scroll container. The problem is, that I don't know the height from the beginning. I have to wait for the backend to tell me and after that the height should stay fix.

I already tried the value `auto` for the height property of the scroll container. This way the scroll container takes the height needed, but I doesn't stay like that.

Any time the screen size changes, the container takes the height to it's content. So it's not scrollable anymore.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for the server response and set the scrollcontainer height in success handler:

```
oModel.read("/Entity", {
success: function (oResponse) {
    this.getView().byId("myScrollContainer").setHeight(oResponse.heightFromBackend + "px");
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you. That way I need to do some logic in the backend but it works